# objective-c use cocoapods add Swift framework not found file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm working on an objective-c project. I added a swift framework, which gave me errors.
When I touch "command" can find the file. When I use #import also can add "ChartLineView.swift".
But when I implement it as,

```
ChartLineView *cl = ....
```

I get an error, " Use of undeclared identifier `LineChartView`"
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your are having issue in importing swift library(added via cocoapods) in your Objective C project. Just go in your .m file and import the swift library like this.

```
@import LineChartView; // i suppose  LineChartView is the swift library name.
```

Comment: thinks! i add @import Chart;   ok